# how many types of parsers are available for android

Tags: android

I have used the SAX parser and the DOM parser. Are there any other parsers that can be used in Android?
PS. I know that these parsers are present in the JDK and have nothing to do with Android, but when I am asking for Android it is implied that I am asking for Java as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All parsers of XML specific ones?

Comment: "but i when i am asking for android it is implied that i am asking for java as well." -> It is quite the opposite. Java parsers work in Android, but Android parsers could not work on Java.

Comment: does not matter, i am asking for android. there is a tag associated with this question which says android and also the question has a very lucid heading -"how many types of parsers are available for android". There is no dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the SAX and DOM parsers, there's also [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).